# I wanted to upgrade OS from 16 to 18 through CLI

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, updates, do-release-upgrade

First, I used this command 
**Sudo apt update**
The result was this

```
 sudo apt update
```

```
    Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                                                                                                         
    Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                
    Ign:3 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell-service InRelease                                                                                              
    Ign:4 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell-vegas-kbl InRelease                                                                       
    Ign:5 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell InRelease                                                      
    Hit:6 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell-service Release                                                
    Hit:8 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell-vegas-kbl Release                                                                         
    Hit:10 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell Release                                                                                  
    Ign:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                              
    Hit:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                   
    Hit:14 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                      
    Hit:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                                 
    Hit:16 https://d3nt0h4h6pmmc4.cloudfront.net/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                       
    Hit:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                         
    Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease                                                                 
    Hit:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty Release                                                                     
    Get:21 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease [6,259 B]                                                 
    Err:21 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                      
      The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
    Hit:23 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                    
    Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial InRelease                          
    Get:25 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ InRelease [1,562 B]
    Err:25 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ InRelease
      The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DFA175A75104960E
    Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
    Err:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial Release     
      403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
    Reading package lists... Done                      
    W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list:3
    W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
    E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
    W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DFA175A75104960E
    E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ InRelease' is not signed.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
    E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
    W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list:3
```

Then I use this command 
**Sudo apt upgrade**
The result was this

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libjson-c2:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libvulkan1
The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files bsdutils distro-info-data dmidecode gnome-software gnome-software-common google-chrome-stable grub-common grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed
  grub2-common initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core libblkid1 libfdisk1 libmount1 libprocps4 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulse0:i386 libpulsedsp
  libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib libsmartcols1 libsnapd-glib1 libuuid1 mount procps pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils
  python3-distupgrade python3-gdbm python3.6 python3.6-minimal skypeforlinux snapd snapd-xdg-open ubuntu-core-launcher ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
  ubuntu-software unattended-upgrades util-linux uuid-runtime
48 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,499 kB/175 MB of archives.
After this operation, 30.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  python3.6 libpython3.6-stdlib python3.6-minimal libpython3.6-minimal python3-gdbm
Authentication warning overridden.
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3.6 amd64 3.6.8-1~16.04.york3
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libpython3.6-stdlib amd64 3.6.8-1~16.04.york3
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3.6-minimal amd64 3.6.8-1~16.04.york3
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libpython3.6-minimal amd64 3.6.8-1~16.04.york3                                                               
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3-gdbm amd64 3.6.5-3~16.04.york4                                                                       
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/python3.6_3.6.8-1~16.04.york3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]               

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.8-1~16.04.york3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/python3.6-minimal_3.6.8-1~16.04.york3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6-minimal_3.6.8-1~16.04.york3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-stdlib-extensions/python3-gdbm_3.6.5-3~16.04.york4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Then I use this command 
** Sudo apt dist-upgrade**
The result was

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libjson-c2:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libvulkan1
The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files bsdutils distro-info-data dmidecode gnome-software gnome-software-common google-chrome-stable grub-common grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed
  grub2-common initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core libblkid1 libfdisk1 libmount1 libprocps4 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulse0:i386 libpulsedsp
  libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib libsmartcols1 libsnapd-glib1 libuuid1 mount procps pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils
  python3-distupgrade python3-gdbm python3.6 python3.6-minimal skypeforlinux snapd snapd-xdg-open ubuntu-core-launcher ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
  ubuntu-software unattended-upgrades util-linux uuid-runtime
48 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,499 kB/175 MB of archives.
After this operation, 30.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  python3.6 libpython3.6-stdlib python3.6-minimal libpython3.6-minimal python3-gdbm
Authentication warning overridden.
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3.6 amd64 3.6.8-1~16.04.york3
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libpython3.6-stdlib amd64 3.6.8-1~16.04.york3
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3.6-minimal amd64 3.6.8-1~16.04.york3
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libpython3.6-minimal amd64 3.6.8-1~16.04.york3                                                               
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3-gdbm amd64 3.6.5-3~16.04.york4                                                                       
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/python3.6_3.6.8-1~16.04.york3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]               

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.8-1~16.04.york3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/python3.6-minimal_3.6.8-1~16.04.york3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6-minimal_3.6.8-1~16.04.york3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-stdlib-extensions/python3-gdbm_3.6.5-3~16.04.york4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

then I run this command 
**Sudo apt-get autoremove**
the result is

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 48 not upgraded.
```

Then I run this command 
**Sudo apt install update-manager-core**
the result was

```
 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version (1:16.04.17).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 48 not upgraded.
```

then I run the command 
**sudo do-release-upgrade**
The result was

```
    Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong and what sort of upgrade is missed from my side

Comment: Before upgrade, your system needs to be healthy and fully updated. Try "sudo apt update" before "upgrade". If you have problems with foreign PPA's, remove the software that came from that PPA and remove the PPA. During upgrading, the upgrader automatically will disable other foreign PPA's.

Comment: I run "sudo run update" before "upgrade" but I don't understand about the PPA thing of software, please explain.

Comment: Looks like you made several mistakes. You must be willing to research and learn how to fix them. See the linked duplicate to learn about the important error that you must fix. There are others of less importance.

Comment: done but still, error is coming